# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable Odoo 11 custom report

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, qweb, odoo-11

I'm trying to create a custom report, i've followed some code i've found on Odoo github but it doesn't work.

First, i'm creating a transiant model with a function that get my data and put it in a python dict :

```
from odoo import api, fields, models
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class SockValuationReport(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'report.stock_valuation_flora'
    _description = 'Sotck valuation report for floravert'

    @api.multi
    def render_report(self):
        products = self.env['product.template'].search([])
        data = {}
        categ_dict = {}
        for product in products:
            valuation = 0
            if(product.categ_id.name in categ_dict):
                valuation = product.standard_price * product.qty_available
                categ_dict[product.categ_id.name]['valuation'] = categ_dict[product.categ_id.name]['valuation'] + valuation
            else:
                categ_dict[product.categ_id.name] = {'categ_name':product.categ_id.name, 'valuation':product.standard_price * product.qty_available}
        data['products'] = products
        data['categ_value']= categ_dict
        _logger.info(data)
        return self.env.ref('stock_printer.report_stock_product_valuation').report_action(self,data=data)
```

next i'm creating a report object in my view.xml file :

```
<report
      id="report_stock_product_valuation"
      model="report.stock_valuation_flora"
      string="Stock Report"
      report_type="qweb-pdf"
      name="stock_printer.report_stock_valuation"
      file="stock_printer.report_stock_valuation"/>
```

then i'm adding my view template :

```
<template id="report_stock_valuation">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-call="web.internal_layout">
                <div class="page">
                  <h1>MY REPORT</h1>
                  <table style="border-spacing:0;margin-bottom:0;" class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <t t-foreach="data['products']" t-as="product">
                          <span t-esc="product.name" />
                        </t>

                      </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </t>
          </t>
        </template>
```

but when i'm trying to print this report i got this error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb\qweb.py", line 341, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_489_36
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_35
  File "<template>", line 3, in body_call_content_34
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1615, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, converter='pdf', **dict(data))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1560, in report_routes
    pdf = report.with_context(context).render_qweb_pdf(docids, data=data)[0]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_actions_report.py", line 624, in render_qweb_pdf
    html = self.with_context(context).render_qweb_html(res_ids, data=data)[0]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_actions_report.py", line 662, in render_qweb_html
    return self.render_template(self.report_name, data), 'html'
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_actions_report.py", line 470, in render_template
    return view_obj.render_template(template, values)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 1189, in render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\web_editor\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 27, in render
    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 1198, in render
    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb\ir_qweb.py", line 57, in render
    return super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb\qweb.py", line 271, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb\qweb.py", line 348, in _compiled_fn
    raise QWebException("Error to render compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb.qweb.QWebException: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_qweb\qweb.py", line 341, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_489_36
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_35
  File "<template>", line 3, in body_call_content_34
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Error to render compiling AST
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Template: 489
Path: /templates/t/t/t/div/table/tbody/t
Node: <t t-foreach="data['products']" t-as="product">
                          <h3 data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-id="489" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/t[1]/t[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/t[1]/h3[1]"></h3>
                        </t>

                            </t>
```

It's looking like my data are not going to my view, but when i'm logging my data before to send it to the view i have a dict with the value i want :

```
{'products': product.template(10, 35, 36, 34, 6, 3, 24, 28, 5, 26, 18, 4, 1, 2, 8, 37, 25, 16, 17, 14, 20, 11, 21, 31, 12, 9, 32, 29, 30, 27, 23, 13, 15, 33, 7, 19, 22, 38), 'categ_value': {'Physique': {'categ_name': 'Physique', 'valuation': 760512.0}, 'En vente': {'categ_name': 'En vente', 'valuation': 0.0}, 'Logiciel': {'categ_name': 'Logiciel', 'valuation': 0.0}, 'Services': {'categ_name': 'Services', 'valuation': 0.0}, 'Tous': {'categ_name': 'Tous', 'valuation': 0.0}}}
```

So i've been trying to make this working for 4 hours and i'm a bit lost actually, if someone know how to fix this, i ll be really happy

Thanks

Edit :

Ok i finally manage to make it work, i've follow the method for the sale detail report and i've done an abstract model that get my data and give it to my view,

I'm still a bit lost about why this was not working before but now it's working

Comment: please add the full error traceback!